# 1001 An Error has occurred. Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have encountered '1001 An Error has occurred.' at runtime in my Silverlight application on some of client machines. This happens when i am handling the KeyDown event of a datagrid. Event gets fired up and i am even able to identify the key that was pressed, however while getting the sellecteditem value this runtime error occurs.

Please note that on some client machines this error is not encountered and everything works fine.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 1001 error is very generic. So it is very hard for us to guess a solution. Are you able to pinpoint it more? Did you monitor network traffic? Perhaps the faulting clients have a slower network connection or a different SL version.

Comment: Thank you Erno.. That client has a lower version of SL.. Used http://www.silverlightversion.com/ to check the version.. After upgrade the runtime error is not there any more.. Thank you once again...

Comment: You're welcome! Note to self. Post answers as answers, not as comments to gather reputation ;-)

Comment: Erno... :) Please do add this as an answer.. I will contribute ;) to your reputation by marking that as an accepted one.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That client has a lower version of SL.. Used silverlightversion.com to check the version.. After upgrade the runtime error is not there any more...